# Alternative measurements cost

Tags: quantum-state, measurement

Most of QKD protocols depends on performing measurements on different basis:

- Some performs the measurements on two basis (standard basis (Z) and the Hadamard basis (X)).
- some performs the measurements  on three basis (x, y, and z)
- some just perform the measurement on the standard basis (Z) and use other measures to secure the protocol

Let us assume I am building the measurement device. **My question** is as follows:

**Is having a device that measures only on one basis  better in terms of cost?**

Is there any way to find the cost and complicity of building these devices?

Best,

Comment: If your quantum devices can readily apply Hadamard transforms robustly (which most useful devices should), then you only need to be able to measure in either the $X$ or $Z$ basis, since the Hadamard $H$ can map you between the two.

Comment: What do you mean by cost? Financially?

Comment: @Rammus, yes financially. Is there a way to quantify the cost of building a measurement device that measures on one basis compared to one that measured on two basis.